# Why is the xUnit XML report truncating the test name value

Tags: xunit, specflow

The complete test name with arguments when executing dotnet test looks like this:

```
[xUnit.net 00:01:43.16] Successfully commence lease by running a Bookie workflow(BusinessUnit: "Default", businessUnit: "707", vendorPartyNumber: "valid", propertyTaxResponsibility: "DoNotRemit", originationSourceType: "Direct", dealType: "Lease", transactionType: "FMV", lineOfBusiness: "Canada", branch: "666457", invoiceFormat: "English", invoiceLeadDays: "25", invoiceDueDay: "30", contractType: "TL", contractTerm: "12", contractPayment: "96.99", contractCommecementDate: "11/30/2017", legalEntity: "Canada", currency: "CAD", assetBookingCurrency: "CAD", invoiceDate: "11/09/2017", invoiceDueDate: "12/23/2017", equipmentDescription: "Inspiron 5680", assetDeliveryDate: "11/16/2017", equipmentAddress1: "760 HWY BEDFORD", equipmentAddress2: "", equipmentCity: "BEDFORD", equipmentState: "NS", equipmentZip: "B4A 3Z7", countryCode: "CAN", equipmentCost: "300", propertyTaxCost: "0.0", lateFeeTemplate: "CAD Daily Late Fee 1.5%", residualAmount: "0", rPAddressLine1: "", rPCity: "", rPZip: "", rPName: "", tapeAccountNumber: "", paymentsArrears: "0", firstPaymentAmount: "21", hasBlendedItems: "false", numberOfPayments: "12", customerCostCenter: "ccc-fit-no-bi", isBargainPurchaseOption: "false", isTaxLease: "true", exampleTags: []) [FAIL]
```

In the Xunit report the test name attribute is truncated like this:

```
<test name="Successfully commence lease by running a Bookie workflow(BusinessUnit: "Default", businessUnit: "707", vendorPartyNumber: "valid", propertyTaxResponsibility: "DoNotRemit", originationSourceType: "Direct", dealType: "Lease", transactionType: "Dollar1Out", lineOfBusiness: "Canada", branch: "666457", invoiceFormat: "English", invoiceLeadDays: "25", invoiceDueDay: "30", contractType: "LP", contractTerm: "12", contractPayment: "96.99",..."
```

Is there a way to have the entire test name with its arguments in the test name in the XML report?

Comment: I formatted the message and XML as code, because the big wall of text was utterly unreadable. As for why this is happening and how to fix it? I wonder if there is a max length for test names? Usually these XML test result files have some schema associated with them. You could try finding the source code for the schema.

Answer (score 1):

Found the code where xUnit runner truncates the test name:

```
const string Ellipsis = "...";

const int MaximumDisplayNameLength = 447;
```

applied here:

```
static string Truncate(string value)
        {
            if (value.Length <= MaximumDisplayNameLength)
                return value;

            return value.Substring(0, MaximumDisplayNameLength - Ellipsis.Length) + Ellipsis;
        }
```